# Android: Mapping JSON into RealmObject with nested JSON objects doesn't work

Tags: android, json, realm

I have a `JSON` string that contains a nested json like

```
{
    "name": "name",
    ...
    ...
    "profile": {
        "id": 987,
        "first_name": "first name"
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to map this `JSON` into `Realm` by using the method `realm.createObjectFromJson(Class clazz, String string)` and the problem is that the nested JSON is not mapped, the resulting `RealmObject` instance that corresponds to the `"profile"` has `0`'s and `null`'s for all the fields. I used `realm.beginTransaction()` before the create operation, and `realm.commitTransaction()` after.

I'm using `'io.realm:realm-android:0.80.1'` for my Android project.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT
These are my model classes. Simple RealmObjects linked together

```
public class SomeClass extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private Profile profile;

    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
}

public class Profile extends RealmObject {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String birthdate;
    private boolean newsLetter;
    private boolean push;
    private int userId;
    private Date lastUpdate;
    private RealmList<RealmAddress> addresses;
    private RealmList<RealmGender> genders;
}
```

the profile class contains only getters and setters, and it contains other Strings and ints, which I deleted for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Can you post your model classes for both the inner and outer class?

Comment: I posted the model classes. RealmAddress is basically a Realm object which contains Strings, same for RealmGender.

Comment: Is it possible that the `Date` is messing things up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON names doesn't match your child object field names which is why you don't see any data. Your `profile` name matches the field in `SomeClass`, which means the object gets created (with default values), but as none of the fields match in `Profile`, none of them are set.

```
firstName != first_name
userId != id
```

If you want to have separate names in your JSON and the Java models you should use something like GSON (http://realm.io/docs/java/#gson) as that is not yet supported by Realm directly.

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing this out! Keep up the good work Realm team, looking forward to checking out other features of the library.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
public class Profile extends RealmObject {
    private String first_name;
    private int id;
    ...
}
```

check  that you have the same names in JSON and your class model